# Java program execution stops abruptly

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying the transposition cipher implementation of Railfence Cipher.

I've taken an example with 3 rails.

The code successfully prints the encrypted code but the problem with the code is that after it stops and does not print the decrypted text. Therefore I could not find the exact location where it stops.

Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class RailfenceCipher
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input=in.nextLine();
    StringBuffer[] rail=new StringBuffer[3];
    for(int t=0;t<3;t++) rail[t]=new StringBuffer();
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(j<input.length()) 
        {
        while(i<=2)
        {
        rail[i].append(input.charAt(j++));
        i++;
        }
        i=1;
        while(i>=0)
        {
        rail[i].append(input.charAt(j++));
        i--;
        }
        i=1;
        }
        else break;
    }
    System.out.println("Enciphered text: ");
    for(int u=0;u<3;u++)
    {
        System.out.print(""+rail[u]);
    }
    StringBuffer decipher=new StringBuffer();
    int tot=0,min=rail[0].length();
    for(int u=0;u<3;u++) 
    {
    tot+=rail[u].length();
    min=(rail[u].length()<min)?rail[u].length():min;
    }
    i=0;j=0;
    while(decipher.length()<=tot)
    {{
        while(i<=2)
        {
        decipher.append(rail[i].charAt(j));
        i++;
        }
        i=1;
        j++;
        while(i>=0)
        {
        decipher.append(rail[i].charAt(j));
        i--;
        }
        i=1;
        j++;}
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Deciphered text: ");
    System.out.println(decipher);
 }
}
```

The output I got was:

D:\exp-cipher>javac RailfenceCipher.java

```
D:\exp-cipher>java RailfenceCipher
WEAREDISCOVEREDFLEEATONCE
Enciphered text:
WECRLTEERDSOEEFEAOCAIVDEN
```

Comment: The program does not stop but goes into an endless loop. Fire up the debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Also, if you want other people to read your code, you need to pay attention to the style, particularly the indentation.